# While Server request is pending, disabled the dropdown selection

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to disable the dropdown selection when the server request is pending. What do I have to do with promise status to keep track of the the status and try to disable the drop list with it?

````
import {withTranslation} from 'react-i18next';
import styles from './main-screen.css';
import {cellProviderUpdateData} from '../api.js';

class CellNetworkProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    selectData(evt){
        let cellID = evt.target.value;
        cellProviderUpdateData(cellID).then(()=>{
            this.props.refreshData();

        });

    }

    isEnabled(e){
        let newId = e.target.value;

    }

    render() { 
        const info = this.props.info;
        const {t} = this.props;
        //const isEnabled = ((e)=> {e.target.value}) != ((evt) =>{this.selectData(evt)});

        return ( 
            <div className = {styles.firstBox}>
            <label className= {styles.label}>{t('CNP')}</label>
            <p>  </p>
                <select className = "select"
                /*  disabled = {!isEnabled} */
                 value = {info.digitalConfiguration}
                 onChange = {(evt) =>{this.selectData(evt)}}>
                    <option value = "Vodafone">Vodafone</option>
                    <option value = "Verizon">Verizon</option>
                </select>

                </div>
         );
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(CellNetworkProvider);```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
class CellNetworkProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            isEnabled : false};
    }

    selectData(evt){
        let cellID = evt.target.value;
        this.setState({
            isEnabled: true
        });
        cellProviderUpdateData(cellID).then(()=>{
            this.props.refreshData()
            this.setState({
                isEnabled: false
            })

        })

    }



    render() { 
        const info = this.props.info;
        const {t} = this.props;

        return ( 
            <div className = {styles.firstBox}>
            <label className= {styles.label}>{t('CNP')}</label>
            <p>  </p>
                <select className = "select"
                 value = {info.digitalConfiguration}
                 onChange = {(evt) =>{this.selectData(evt)}}
                 disabled = {this.state.isEnabled}>
                    <option value = "Vodafone">Vodafone</option>
                    <option value = "Verizon">Verizon</option>

                </select>

                </div>
         );
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(CellNetworkProvider);
```